# where is the problem vector find c++ ??

Tags: c++, iterator, find

when i compile i has an error and i cannot understand where is the problem?

```
class Edge{  
public:  
      int nid;  
      bool operator==(const Edge& edge) const {  
            return nid == edge.nid;  
      }  
 };
```

and problem here

```
vector<Edge> edges;  
vector<Edge>::iterator it;  
it = find (edges.begin(), edges.end(), nid);

if( it != edges.end() )  
      edges.erase(it);
```

any ideas ?!!!?

Comment: what is your problem? A compile error or runtime error? You don't put anything in your vector in your sample code but I guess you skipped that part for the example?

Comment: what does the error say?
what is the find method signature?

Comment: What is `nid` declared as in the second example?

Comment: it is a compile error and nid is int that i wants to match with nid in Edge class

Comment: dawnlight: Well, we can't give you much help if you don't show us the error.

Comment: ....almost there: what is the error exactly?

Comment: return std::find(__first, __last, __val,std::__iterator_category(__first)); i have a mark on this line of stl_algo.h

Comment: the method find defined in algorithm is:
template <class InputIterator, class T>
   InputIterator find ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value );
So, your 3rd parameter must be of type Edge.

Comment: the problem that i dont have an error on my code so i dont know what is the error but i am sure that find is the method that make the error !!

Comment: That's the line that gives the error, not the error message. We need the text saying what's wrong.

Comment: @Klaimmore ... thanks, the error is no longer appears. i didnot notice that it should be same type maybe because all examples are int !!! but is there a method like find but i need to compare by edge id which is int ???

Comment: @dawnlight just use find. It is as easy as to declare an object of type Edge and set its nid equal to your id. Your operator == only uses the id for comparison, so its ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` will compare (with `==`) the objects of type `Edge` in the vector with `nid`. I guess that `nid` is of type `int` and that won't work unless you implement `operator==` between `Edge` and `int`.

You can try :

```
it = find (edges.begin(), edges.end(), Edge(nid));
```

Comment: That's correct. However I don't think the method find would work with an int as 3rd parameter, it doesn't matter if you implement operator== between Edge and int.

Comment: @Klaimmore I don't have time to compile a test case right now but I'm pretty sure it would work by reimplementing operator==. The find algorithm only needs that both values are comparable by operator==, not that they have the same type (see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find.html )

Comment: That's an interesting link. However I tested it on cygwin and it didnt compile.

Comment: @Klaimmore I made a test case, it compiled just fine with visual c++. I defined the operator like this (inside class Edge) : `bool operator==(int rval) const { return nid == rval; }` maybe there's something wrong with your code or your compiler ?

Comment: You're right, something went wrong yesterday with my development environment. It turns out that they just need to be comparable.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't described the extract symptoms of your problem, but I guess that it is related to that didn't define the `operator!=`

You probably want to define it as

```
   bool operator!=(const Edge&edge)const {
      return !(*this == edge);
   }
```

also if your find(...,nid) is taking nid as an integer argument, you probably also need to overload the == operator as

```
   bool operator==(const int&edge)const {
      return this->nid == edge;
   }
```

Comment: i added a != operator and it did not help

Comment: +1 for recognizing the need for `Edge::operator==(const int&) const`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either overload the operator!=, too, or simply negate the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nid is the same type as in the class I assume you get a complaint about the type of the third argument to find(). I think you can switch it to:

```
vector<Edge>::iterator it = find (edges.begin(), edges.end(), edges.begin() + nid);
```